# Resize function won't work with check width and scroll function

Tags: jquery

I have a check width function that checks the width of a screen then performs a scroll function.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(window).on('resize', checkWidthStickyHeader);
function checkWidthStickyHeader() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 1350) {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
                jQuery('.header-top').addClass('header-top-active');
            }
            else {
                jQuery('.header-top').removeClass('header-top-active');
            }
        });
    } else {
        
    }
}
checkWidthStickyHeader();
```

So basically what this is saying, is that if the browser is above 1350px then perform a scroll function. If it is less than 1350px then do nothing.

This works, but you have to refresh the page for it to check the width of the window again.

To have it check the width on resize I added that thing at the top `jQuery(window).on('resize', checkWidthStickyHeader)`.

This seems to work because I did a `console.log` test in the else statement at the bottom and that was firing every time I resized the window.

But here is the issue, when you start at a screen width bigger than 1350px and the shrink it to a value below that, the scroll function still fires. I'm not sure why it does this.

Comment: you have to unregister your scroll event in the else block  jQuery(window).off("scroll", scrollHandler); or check the width inside the scroll function

Comment: @karthick awesome I just checked the width inside the scroll function and it worked! could you post that as an answer so i can accept it and give you reputation?

Comment: sure. thanks. I suggest the former approach. But it's your call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to unregister your scrollHandler or check the width inside the scroll function.

```
Example: Register/unregister scroll
jQuery(window).on('resize', checkWidthStickyHeader);


    function addStickyness(){
                    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
                        jQuery('.header-top').addClass('header-top-active');
                    }
                    else {
                        jQuery('.header-top').removeClass('header-top-active');
                    }
        }

    function checkWidthStickyHeader() {
        if (jQuery(window).width() > 1350) {
            jQuery(window).on('scroll',addStickyness);
        } else {
            jQuery(window).off('scroll', addStickyness)
        }
    }
    checkWidthStickyHeader();
```